# How to apply a permutation to a symmetric square matrix?

Tags: matrix, combinatorics, permutation

Given a symmetric square matrix, how can I apply a permutation to the rows and columns (i.e. the same permutation to both the rows and the columns) such a way that the new structure of the matrix should follow the new row and column order?

Consider an order of rows/columns, according to which the elements of a set are arranged in a matrix:

```
order = Range[5];
matrix = Table[Subscript[a, i, j], {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
TableForm[matrix, TableHeadings -> {order, order}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now take a permutation of the row/column order:

```
newOrder = RandomSample[order]
(*
   ==> {1, 4, 5, 2, 3}
*)
```

`FindPermutation` finds the appropriate permutation cycle for the new order:

```
permutation = FindPermutation[order, newOrder]
Permute[order, permutation]
(*
   ==> Cycles[{{2, 4}, {3, 5}}]
   ==> {1, 4, 5, 2, 3}
*)
```

Now the question is: **How to easily and elegantly apply the above permutation (preferably in its `Cycles` form) to the matrix to yield the following one**:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Some notes:

- The `matrix` is always square and symmetric.
- Column and head orders are always identical.
- Bear in mind that `order`, and consequently `matrix`, can be big (e.g. `4^8` for `order`)
- Since `matrix` can be big, I'm looking for a method, that applies the permutation 'locally', that is without reconstructing the whole table every time, or without applying replacements/functions enumerating each element, thus no dispatch table should be used. This is rather important, as it could be that the new order only swaps two columns/rows, and nothing else.

Comment: Related question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258349/how-to-form-submatrices-with-some-non-consecutive-rows-and-columns-of-a-matrix/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about:

```
ord = {1, 4, 5, 2, 3}
matrix[[ord, ord]]
```

(You can convert any permutation (including `Cycles`) to an index list using `PermutationList`.)

Comment: Amazingly simple. Shame on me.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @Istvan the solution is simple, but IMHO not trivial.  It's a good question.