# Sort two lists at the same time, based on another

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, permutation

I am new to using Mathematica and I can not find a solution to what I am wanting to do.

I want to take a list such as:

```
x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

and a second list (permutation):

```
perm = {4,1,6,2,7,3,8,5}
```

and get a result to where the permutation is applied to x. So the return would be 2,4,6,1,8,3,5,7.

My goal is a function like permutationEncrypt[x_, permutation_] := return x with the permutation applied to it

I know I can sort a list, but how would I accomplish what I am wanting to do?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please add code that you have attempted to use to solve this problem.

Comment: Related: [(2323)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2323/121), [(56848)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56848/121)

Answer (score 6):

A simple way is:

```
y = x; y[[perm]] = x; y
(* {2, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Permute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permute.html) gives what you expect to get from `permutationEncrypt`:

```
Permute[x, perm]
(* {2, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

You can also use `Ordering`:

```
peF[x_, p_] := x[[Ordering @ p]]

peF[x, perm]
(* {2, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

Or, `ReplaceAll`:

```
peF2 = # /. Thread[#2 -> #] &;

peF2[x, perm]
(* {2, 4, 6, 1, 8, 3, 5, 7} *)
```

Comment: I think that last one should be `Range@Length@x /.`

Answer (score 3):

Timings for the methods posted:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

f1[{x_, perm_}] := Permute[x, perm]
f2[{x_, perm_}] := x[[Ordering @ perm]]
f3[{x_, perm_}] := Table[x[[Position[perm, i][[1, 1]]]], {i, Length[x]}]
f4[{x_, perm_}] := Module[{y = x}, y[[perm]] = x; y]

BenchmarkPlot[
 {f1, f2, f3, f4},
 {RandomInteger[99, #], RandomSample@Range@#} &,
 TimeConstraint -> 15
]
```

[image]

So it seems Simon's code beats the built-in function. :^)

Answer (score 0):

Although not as elegant, this also works.

```
Table[x[[Position[perm, i][[1, 1]]]], {i, Length[x]}]
```