# How to order a list to match the order of another list?

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

How can I order a list to match the order of anoter list ?

For example: Suppose I have the lists `x = {3, 1, 5, 7}` and `y = {3, 7, 1, 5}`. How can I order `x` to have the order of `y`?

This question is interesting when each element of `x` has composite values, for example, as a list or an association.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `Ordering` it's possible to do this. `Ordering` can be seen as a permutation that brings a list to the identity permutation. And applying `Ordering` again to this permutation we get the inverse permutation that brings a list from identity to the original order. Using these observations:

```
OrderingToTarget[list_, sourceIds_, targetIds_] :=
  list[[Ordering @ sourceIds]][[Ordering @ Ordering@targetIds]]

OrderingToTarget[x, x, y]
```

Comment: You are right, it is fast and traditional way to do a such kind of sorting. Related: [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56868/4678), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4545223/2379045), [3](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2007/Jun/msg00920.html). Anyway, +1, I cannot find similar Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Sort two lists at the same time, based on another](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73110/121) here is a different approach:

```
permuteLike[a_, b_] :=
  Module[{x = a},
    x[[Ordering @ b]] = Sort[a];
    x
  ]
```

This proves to be somewhat faster and I find it somehow more pleasing as well.

```
a = {"f", "a", "h", "y", "c", "d"};
b = {"w", "t", "q", "o", "b", "p"};

OrderingToTarget[a, a, b]

a ~permuteLike~ b
```

> ```
> {"y", "h", "f", "c", "a", "d"}
>
> {"y", "h", "f", "c", "a", "d"}
> ```

```
{a, b} = RandomInteger[3*^6, {2, 1*^6}];

OrderingToTarget[a, a, b] // RepeatedTiming // First

a ~permuteLike~ b         // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.3234
>
> 0.228
> ```