# Rearranging matrix rows using a list

Tags: matrix

Surely there is a simple answer to this:

Suppose $ R = [3\,1\,2] $ and $ A $ is any matrix with three rows.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 4 \\ 5 &2 \\ 0 & 3 \\ \end{bmatrix} $$

Is there a way to create a new matrix, $ B $, whose rows are specified by entries of $ R $? In other words the first row of $ B $ is the third row of $ A $, the second row of $ B $ is the first row of $ A $, and the third row of $ B $ is the second row of $ A $.

I've tried `B = A[[R, All]]`, which is analogous to what I'd do in Matlab, `B=A(I,:)`.

Comment: `Permute[A, InversePermutation@R]` or `Extract[A, List /@ R]`.

Comment: Doesn't `A[[R]]` give what you want?

Comment: Thanks--all three of those seem to work!

Comment: See also: [(2323)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2323/121),
[(73110)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73110/121)

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, there are several ways to do that. The easiest method is

```
A[[R]]
```

Although you could use

```
Extract[A, List /@ R]
```

or

```
Permute[A, InversePermutation@R]
```

as well.